# Select2 Ajax results could not be loaded

Tags: ajax, jquery-select2, ajaxform, jquery-select2-4, ui-select2

Whenever I try to search for result in my select2 ajax searchbar I receive the following message:

> 'The results could not be loaded'

**Html**:

```
<select class="js-data-example-ajax form-control" multiple="multiple"></select>
```

**Javascript**:

```
$('select').each(function(idx, ele) {
            $(ele).select2({
                theme: 'bootstrap4',
                placeholder: ele.getAttribute('placeholder'),
                ajax: {
                    url: '/product/api/search',
                    dataType: 'json' },
                    type: 'GET',
            });
        });
```

I think that my Ajax settings are wrong could you assist?

Comment: if you call /product/api/search in browser you got valid json for select2 like id and text?

Comment: also your ajax script is not ended properly. You need to move } from dataType at the end of ajax

Comment: @daremachine Yes it's returning results in JSON, could you provide me with a answer with the correct syntax?

Comment: look at processResults in doc https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like this. No GET method needed.

```
$('select').each(function(idx, ele) {
  $(ele).select2({
      ajax: {
        url: 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories',
        dataType: 'json'
        // Additional AJAX parameters
      }
   }
});
```

Also your problem might be in your source json format because select2 need own format with `results`.

> In order to accomplish this, Select2 expects a very specific data
>   format. This format consists of a JSON object containing an array of
>   objects keyed by the results key.

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "text": "Option 1"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "text": "Option 2"
    }
}
```

Also you can use [processResults or transform](https://select2.org/data-sources/formats) data into certain format.

Comment: Thanks, i get the result in the searchbar but the search query on a specific name is not working ? What could be the reason for this?

Comment: what you mean specific name in query? you have not query

Comment: For example i have 10 results in json if I search for id 2 with text "Option 2" it does not filter to option 2. I will still see the whole list.

Comment: and you search in select2 or server side? if you want to filter by server side you need implement q term parameter. I can not help you because you probably dont know what you do. Read documentation how to deal with ajax.

Comment: Aren't you missing a closing square bracket in this example?